# Can't use loaded components angularjs2

Tags: angular

Here's my code for the app:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig,RouterLink, Location} from 'angular2/router';
import { About } from "./components/about";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:'<h1>{{title}}</h1>'
})

@RouteConfig( [
    { path: "/", as: "Home", component: AppComponent },
    { path: "/about", as: "About", component: About}
] )
class AppComponent {
    public title = 'Home';
}
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And here's the code for my component:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector:"about",
    template:'<h1>{{title}}</h1>'
})

export class About{
    public title = 'About';
}
```

For some reason, if I remove About from the `@RouteConfig` I can show the main page at least, but with the route to the about component, I always get:

```
Uncaught Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://test.local/src/app/components/about
```

Someone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you add a plunker?

Comment: It doesn't work with typescript

Answer (score 0):

Where http://test.local/src/ comes from?
Since you haven't specified the LocationStrategy Angular uses PathLocationStrategy by default. In this case you need to specify the value for the base URL using APP_BASE_HREF, e.g.

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})
]);

Comment: I added this, but it doesn't fix the issue unfortunatly

Comment: Try adding the code of the About component to the file with AppComponent. If this will work, see what's wrong in with SystemJS config.

Comment: Great idea, will try!

Comment: So I don't get the error anymore, so that's something. But the routes are not working.